# ffmpeg- number of frames

Tags: ffmpeg, frames

I am streaming live feed of a webcam from PC A to PC B, both connected to a router. I am streaming the video using ffmpeg and I have the output of the commands I use at A and B as follows,

```
Started at Mon Jun 11 12:51:46 CDT 2018
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 526453.330073, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for MPEG-2 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
Output #0, mpegts, to 'tcp://172.16.0.169:50000':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] config in time_base: 1/1000000, frame_rate: 30/1
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:059C8C1C plane_checksum:[059C8C1C] mean:[128 ] stdev:[28.1 ]
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #1, mp4, to '/home/sana/Desktop/sender_new/sender_mp4/tcp10wf.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   1 pts:  32000 pts_time:0.032   pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:A8C0B7F7 plane_checksum:[A8C0B7F7] mean:[125 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   2 pts:  63999 pts_time:0.063999 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:F8EAFA02 plane_checksum:[F8EAFA02] mean:[125 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   3 pts:  96003 pts_time:0.096003 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:8349B90A plane_checksum:[8349B90A] mean:[124 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   4 pts: 132004 pts_time:0.132004 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:B67CB4C2 plane_checksum:[B67CB4C2] mean:[124 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   5 pts: 164003 pts_time:0.164003 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:E05C3BA2 plane_checksum:[E05C3BA2] mean:[124 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   6 pts: 195998 pts_time:0.195998 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:2C9F5E9C plane_checksum:[2C9F5E9C] mean:[123 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   7 pts: 232070 pts_time:0.23207 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:46521311 plane_checksum:[46521311] mean:[122 ] stdev:[28.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   8 pts: 264011 pts_time:0.264011 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:C7B37767 plane_checksum:[C7B37767] mean:[122 ] stdev:[28.3 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:   9 pts: 296061 pts_time:0.296061 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:6C1E0DF5 plane_checksum:[6C1E0DF5] mean:[123 ] stdev:[27.6 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  10 pts: 332007 pts_time:0.332007 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:7EDC1257 plane_checksum:[7EDC1257] mean:[124 ] stdev:[26.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  11 pts: 364006 pts_time:0.364006 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:F47CF25B plane_checksum:[F47CF25B] mean:[124 ] stdev:[26.7 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  12 pts: 396007 pts_time:0.396007 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:34BEAC53 plane_checksum:[34BEAC53] mean:[124 ] stdev:[27.5 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  13 pts: 432049 pts_time:0.432049 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:44B21C5E plane_checksum:[44B21C5E] mean:[124 ] stdev:[28.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  14 pts: 464006 pts_time:0.464006 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:B9449349 plane_checksum:[B9449349] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.5 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  15 pts: 496010 pts_time:0.49601 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:51C6DCE5 plane_checksum:[51C6DCE5] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.8 ]
frame=   16 fps=0.0 q=19.1 q=0.0 size=      92kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=1742.3kbits/s speed=0.857x    
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  16 pts: 532019 pts_time:0.532019 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:AD50363E plane_checksum:[AD50363E] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  17 pts: 564008 pts_time:0.564008 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:6F75F7A5 plane_checksum:[6F75F7A5] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  18 pts: 596009 pts_time:0.596009 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:B3B4DD3A plane_checksum:[B3B4DD3A] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  19 pts: 632005 pts_time:0.632005 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:AF98B81C plane_checksum:[AF98B81C] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  20 pts: 664012 pts_time:0.664012 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:BD809E30 plane_checksum:[BD809E30] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  21 pts: 696073 pts_time:0.696073 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:30C0816F plane_checksum:[30C0816F] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  22 pts: 732013 pts_time:0.732013 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:BC8498BA plane_checksum:[BC8498BA] mean:[123 ] stdev:[28.9 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  23 pts: 764070 pts_time:0.76407 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:6828551A plane_checksum:[6828551A] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  24 pts: 796014 pts_time:0.796014 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:2C381775 plane_checksum:[2C381775] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  25 pts: 832024 pts_time:0.832024 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:B21BA7D8 plane_checksum:[B21BA7D8] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  26 pts: 864011 pts_time:0.864011 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:3F170D6F plane_checksum:[3F170D6F] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  27 pts: 896015 pts_time:0.896015 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:4F982F14 plane_checksum:[4F982F14] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  28 pts: 932073 pts_time:0.932073 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:0BD2826C plane_checksum:[0BD2826C] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  29 pts: 964016 pts_time:0.964016 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:1C82D871 plane_checksum:[1C82D871] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.4 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x5633adea81c0] n:  30 pts: 996013 pts_time:0.996013 pos:       -1 fmt:yuyv422 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:073C2E08 plane_checksum:[073C2E08] mean:[123 ] stdev:[29.4 ]
frame=   31 fps= 31 q=15.3 q=0.0 size=     115kB time=00:00:00.93 bitrate=1012.0kbits/s speed=0.924x
......................................
......................................
video:2301kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] frame I:6     Avg QP:20.14  size: 16164
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] frame P:356   Avg QP:22.44  size:  1117
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] frame B:1053  Avg QP:23.78  size:   221
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  0.1%  0.2% 98.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] mb I  I16..4: 29.9% 53.6% 16.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  0.7%  0.1%  P16..4: 22.6%  1.7%  2.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:72.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  8.6%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:90.9%  L0:38.6% L1:59.1% BI: 2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] 8x8 transform intra:54.6% inter:81.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.8% 63.6% 21.7% inter: 0.9% 6.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] i16 v,h,dc,p:  5% 21%  2% 71%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 21% 12%  7%  7%  6%  9%  8%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 29%  9%  4%  6%  5% 10%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 54% 17% 23%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.7% UV:0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] ref P L0: 65.0%  4.9% 21.3%  8.8%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] ref B L0: 90.2%  8.5%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] ref B L1: 95.3%  4.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5633ade11c00] kb/s:123.38
```

and output at B is as follows,

```
`enter code here`Input #0, mpegts, from 'tcp://172.16.0.169:50000?listen':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1.433333, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv422p(tv, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] config in time_base: 1/90000, frame_rate: 30/1
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:      564 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:C4C468FE plane_checksum:[D95CF033 55257422 E595049A] mean:[116 133 135 ] stdev:[53.9 21.2 24.8 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - unknown side data type 12 (8 bytes)
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x564b1590fd80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x564b1590fd80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x564b1590fd80] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x564b1590fd80] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/sana/Desktop/receiver_new/receiver_new_mp4/tcp10wf.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   1 pts:   3000 pts_time:0.0333333 pos:   160740 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:ABE94737 plane_checksum:[9EBD5B29 764AF3E3 D38AF80D] mean:[217 128 130 ] stdev:[29.5 2.8 4.3 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   2 pts:   6000 pts_time:0.0666667 pos:   180480 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:E0B4988D plane_checksum:[4E367382 03AEE4B1 318F404B] mean:[216 128 130 ] stdev:[30.3 3.5 3.4 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - unknown side data type 12 (8 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   3 pts:   9000 pts_time:0.1     pos:   197588 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:B1C91876 plane_checksum:[AB0F6A6E 6CC6578E E607566B] mean:[132 129 128 ] stdev:[41.4 3.3 3.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   4 pts:  12000 pts_time:0.133333 pos:   229736 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:8BA7FB44 plane_checksum:[5DEF68EE E8213305 17EB5F51] mean:[132 129 128 ] stdev:[41.4 3.3 3.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   5 pts:  15000 pts_time:0.166667 pos:   231804 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:AD4C2994 plane_checksum:[24819277 A69D34D4 B3CD623A] mean:[132 129 128 ] stdev:[41.4 3.3 3.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   6 pts:  18000 pts_time:0.2     pos:   232556 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:7AD4A9FF plane_checksum:[F2328134 6200B528 45A97394] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   7 pts:  21000 pts_time:0.233333 pos:   244588 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:942BD05A plane_checksum:[5ABAA382 B8B0B726 FD1B75A3] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   8 pts:  24000 pts_time:0.266667 pos:   245528 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:78F6F66E plane_checksum:[4C33C2B1 E905BB7E 064B7830] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:   9 pts:  27000 pts_time:0.3     pos:   246092 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:637EFB0B plane_checksum:[D25DC425 30A7BD43 069D7994] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  10 pts:  30000 pts_time:0.333333 pos:   246656 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9E78061E plane_checksum:[9C27CBE2 DB4ABF7E 267D7AA0] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  11 pts:  33000 pts_time:0.366667 pos:   247220 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:08E014FD plane_checksum:[69E7D8AA B0E2C07F 6F557BB6] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  12 pts:  36000 pts_time:0.4     pos:   247784 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:87DA207B plane_checksum:[2E59E1CF 3AABC10A D1E97D84] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  13 pts:  39000 pts_time:0.433333 pos:   248348 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:914F3267 plane_checksum:[EBC0F215 BD45C2D3 AC0A7D61] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  14 pts:  42000 pts_time:0.466667 pos:   248912 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9948509D plane_checksum:[CC2F0C83 ED75C5A9 210E7E62] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 3.0 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - unknown side data type 12 (8 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  15 pts:  45000 pts_time:0.5     pos:   249852 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:2910004A plane_checksum:[534C140D 40CEE6CC 4EF70562] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  16 pts:  48000 pts_time:0.533333 pos:   263200 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:6BBB211A plane_checksum:[78712F93 80CAE91F A3100859] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  17 pts:  51000 pts_time:0.566667 pos:   263952 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:ACF52F6A plane_checksum:[B1EB3C80 4FC8E9A1 9CED093A] mean:[109 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  18 pts:  54000 pts_time:0.6     pos:   264328 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:18206027 plane_checksum:[31466208 09F60A1D 12DAF3F3] mean:[113 129 128 ] stdev:[40.6 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  19 pts:  57000 pts_time:0.633333 pos:   268276 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:64B67919 plane_checksum:[685A7A8E 3EC50A6E 33B6F40E] mean:[113 129 128 ] stdev:[40.6 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  20 pts:  60000 pts_time:0.666667 pos:   268652 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:2EDF8D96 plane_checksum:[C5478D34 E97E0AD1 A102F582] mean:[113 129 128 ] stdev:[40.6 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  21 pts:  63000 pts_time:0.7     pos:   269216 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:26113995 plane_checksum:[17BE2921 F51A1C4A C9D2F41B] mean:[114 129 128 ] stdev:[40.9 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  22 pts:  66000 pts_time:0.733333 pos:   272224 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:CAA9871C plane_checksum:[943974ED 7B351CE2 0458F53E] mean:[114 129 128 ] stdev:[40.9 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  23 pts:  69000 pts_time:0.766667 pos:   272788 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:C0C1DBB3 plane_checksum:[C2FEC442 0FE01EA7 057AF8BB] mean:[114 129 128 ] stdev:[40.8 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  24 pts:  72000 pts_time:0.8     pos:   273728 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:924A4994 plane_checksum:[833C2885 BD2A22BB B2DBFE45] mean:[115 129 128 ] stdev:[40.8 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  25 pts:  75000 pts_time:0.833333 pos:   274668 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9451D3A0 plane_checksum:[169CAC73 177C25E0 C23E014D] mean:[115 129 128 ] stdev:[40.7 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  26 pts:  78000 pts_time:0.866667 pos:   275232 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:49A639A2 plane_checksum:[4DF60BD9 821F2A4F 108D037A] mean:[115 129 128 ] stdev:[40.7 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - unknown side data type 12 (8 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  27 pts:  81000 pts_time:0.9     pos:   276172 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:FC6359F1 plane_checksum:[B3915D35 4B0DE947 7F961366] mean:[116 129 128 ] stdev:[40.3 2.9 3.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  28 pts:  84000 pts_time:0.933333 pos:   286700 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:B39C9D3F plane_checksum:[34749CEA BA34EAFC E248154A] mean:[116 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  29 pts:  87000 pts_time:0.966667 pos:   287264 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:97FED800 plane_checksum:[300AD70C 0EBEEB31 DEE515B4] mean:[116 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460]   side data - pan/scan
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x564b15967460] n:  30 pts:  90000 pts_time:1       pos:   287828 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:B278FBDC plane_checksum:[6094F812 B757EBEF 839F17CC] mean:[116 129 128 ] stdev:[40.2 2.9 3.0 ]
................................
..................................
frame= 1415 fps= 34 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1047kB time=00:00:47.06 bitrate= 182.2kbits/s speed=1.12x    
video:1032kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.490835%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] frame I:6     Avg QP:16.30  size:  9839
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] frame P:591   Avg QP:20.05  size:  1380
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] frame B:818   Avg QP:22.29  size:   221
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] consecutive B-frames: 20.8%  5.2%  3.0% 71.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] mb I  I16..4: 47.5% 49.8%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] mb P  I16..4:  1.7%  4.8%  0.2%  P16..4: 12.0%  2.2%  2.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:76.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.4%  0.0%  B16..8: 14.5%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.4%  skip:84.3%  L0:60.3% L1:39.3% BI: 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] 8x8 transform intra:67.9% inter:92.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.0% 48.3% 1.9% inter: 1.5% 3.6% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 61% 14%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 22% 52%  2%  0%  0%  1%  1%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 52% 33%  8%  2%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 23% 28%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.3% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] ref P L0: 82.7%  6.2%  7.6%  3.5%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] ref B L0: 71.7% 22.3%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] ref B L1: 93.6%  6.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55b73dba9fc0] kb/s:179.05`
```

I have skipped few lines of output as there are many frames. So if you see at the end of output on both A and B sides and look at the number of I, P and B frames,the number of P and B frames on receiver B is more than that at sender A. Can anyone please tell me why there is a change in the number of frames?

Comment: You've sent a re-encoded (low bitrate MPEG-2) version of the stream to B, so the raw frames fed to the two x264 instances aren't the same, and so the rate-control decisions shouldn't be expected to be the same. Send a rawvideo or lossless stream to B and check.

Comment: I did not care about the encoding while doing this experiment, but I used libx264 to get the number of I, P and B frames at the end. Is there any other way to get such stats at the end of the transmission?

Comment: libx264 is an encoder so it's generating a new stream. Your original input is rawvideo so it has no I/P/B frames since it is not a compressed stream. What exactly are you trying to compare?